# Is it dangerous, that ___tls_get_addr called in 32bit environment?

Tags: c++, c, glibc, libstdc++

We have x86_64 system, but all libraries and applications are built for i386 and we run them in i386 mode.
gdb (and ltrace too) tell us, that ___tls_get_addr is used, that was designed for x86_64 as far, as I can see ([___tls_get_addr gnu](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21609#c4)) and also we have glibc version 2.19-18 (looks like issue was fixed only in glibc-2.24). Is it dangerous, that ___tls_get_addr is called from applications running in i386 mode? How can we fix that problem, if it's a problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, for a C++ program, *all* parts of an application, including libraries it links with, should be built with the *same* exact compiler for the same exact architecture. Otherwise, there are no guarantees of correct behaviour.

Comment: @JesperJuhl looks like we have x86_64 system, that builds i386 packages, with glibc version 2.23 builded with gcc 5.4, and we have 2.19 builded with 4.8.4...

Comment: OK, then just recompile your stuff with the same compiler on the same architecture. Problem solved.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's probably great idea, but not simply realisable. Cause of OS differences. Well, thanks for point, we will try anyway.

Comment: you can get developer versions of compilers backported to older OS's that will behave the same, for example we recently had to get a development version of gcc in order to build our software on redhad 6 (legacy version) because the default compiler on redhat 6 didn't support some features we used

Comment: @JesperJuhl looks like your message was that best. We actually move project to debian stretch with all libraries before - it works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GCC bug in `__tls_get_addr` stack alignment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58066) you reference is specific to x86-64. It does not exist on i386. I'll assume you swapped i386 and x86-64 in your question.

In general, the distribution toolchains are consistent and well-tested. If you compile your programs with the system compiler and use the system glibc version, `__tls_get_addr` will work as expected, even if the GCC bug has not been fixed. The bug only materializes if buggy programs are run with a `malloc` that happens to use vector instructions. With glibc's `malloc`, this only happens with GCC 7 or later. Once Fedora started to use GCC 7 as the system compiler, the incomplete workaround for the GCC bug in glibc was discovered, and a more complete workaround was implemented upstream (and integrated into Fedora). Before the GCC 7 switch, the buggy applications were running just fine.

[Some distributions have backported the fix](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1468807) because they support multiple compilers and `malloc` implementations. In the end, this is a distribution integration issue, so if you have doubts, you need to talk to your distribution support.

`___tls_get_addr` (three underscores) is merely an internal implementation detail. It was visible to some debugging tools in glibc 2.20 and earlier because it was not a hidden symbol. In glibc 2.21 and later, it was made hidden (on i386), and `ltrace` and similar tools will no longer report it. This is merely a minor performance optimization, it does not affect functionality.